# When reviewing "reopen" suggestions, reason(s) for closing aren't shown

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-reopen

While the post to be reopened should stand on its own, it would be useful to see the reason(s) for closing, to check if the objections have been addressed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, just lookes more carefully. It shows up, but seemingly only if there are comments on the post. Not always.